# gganimate - shadow_wake()

Tags: r, ggplot2, shadow, gganimate

In the gganimate package, it is said that it's possible, using the falloff argument, to change only the size or alpha of the wake. Does anyone know how to do this? In my practice, only the falloff/speed of both get changed.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput`?